# Can jutsu be cast across a barrier?

Tags: naruto

Suppose Kabuto was trapped in a barrier created by the Sound Four. Could he make the coffins for Edo Tensei appear outside the barrier?

Comment: That's an interesting question. I think it depends on the barrier type, but generally speaking Chakra should be able to pass through a barrier, so the logical answer is **no**, maybe someone else have other evidence though.

Comment: Would definitly be possible with  a space time ninjutsu such as kamui

Comment: Not unless the technique is significantly stronger than the barrier, otherwise it would be trivial to beat me inside of the Susano'o, with any "remote" technique.

Comment: Looks like Tobi/Obito's and Kakashi's jutsu can go through barriers... time and space? Not too sure though.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it can.
For instance: in the starting Naruto episodes, when Kakashi was trapped in a water ball by Zabuza, he could not get out until Naruto intervened (the first time it was shown that he could use his brain).

So I don't think Jutsu can pass through a Jutsu created barrier, but can break through if its weaker (kind of obvious). In other words, when Jutsu clash, it must be the battle of chakras between the barrier caster(s) and the one trapped.